# NSDictionary Search Time Complexity

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, hashtable, selector, time-complexity

Is the search operation selector objectForKey: of the NSDictionary class of order 1 time complexity like a hashtable?

Comment: Yes. It uses a combination of `hash` and `isEqual`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to have a mostly-link answer, but everything you might want to know and more is here:
[Exposing NSDictionary](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/04/08/exposing-nsdictionary/)

This is the code suggested for `objectForKey`:

```
- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    NSUInteger sizeIndex = _szidx;
    NSUInteger size = __NSDictionarySizes[sizeIndex];

    id *storage = (id *)object_getIndexedIvars(dict);

    NSUInteger fetchIndex = [aKey hash] % size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        id fetchedKey = storage[2 * fetchIndex];

        if (fetchedKey == nil) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (fetchedKey == aKey || [fetchedKey isEqual:aKey]) {
            return storage[2 * fetchIndex + 1];
        }

        fetchIndex++;

        if (fetchIndex == size) {
            fetchIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

As Bartosz Ciechanowski says:

> Worse case performance is ***linear***

[Read the rest!](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/04/08/exposing-nsdictionary/)

He proves that there is definitely object instance == checking before an isEqual test.  And a lot more.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this! Very informative. I see the alternative is to use NSHashTable in iOS 6